# Virtual host 2 domains one mapped to /shorten only?

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu

Below is my current virtual host. I have two domains pointed the server, lets say...

```
domain1.com and domain2.com
```

Both domain currently to seem to work with the virtual host below (even tho I don't have domain2.com in the virtual host).

My problem is that I only want domain2.com to work when the url has forward slash /shorten/ i.e. domain2.com/pages/

How can this be done with the current host file below?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain1.com
ServerAlias domain1.com *.domain1.com
DocumentRoot /srv/project/foo



 Alias /static "/srv/project/foo/public/common"
    <Location "/static/">
        SetHandler None
    </Location>

<Directory /srv/project/foo/apache>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess domain1.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup domain1.com

WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/project/foo/apache/django.wsgi
ErrorLog /srv/project/logs/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: you can use `mod_rewrite` in `.htaccess` file?